# Fit table text to page width (table fits but nor text)

Tags: tables

I guess this is a common question and am able to fit the table to textwidth using tabularx package. But the text within the table does not fit in. I think I am missing a small detail? Appreciate your help.[image]

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\small
\captionsetup{font=small}
\centering
\caption{Description of the features employed in this project.}
\label{table:1}
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{l||l}
\toprule
\textbf{Feature} & \textbf{Description}\\ \hline
Zero Crossing Rate & The rate of sign-changes of the signal during the duration of a particular frame. \\ \hline
Energy & The sum of squares of the signal values, normalized by the respective frame length. \\ \hline
Entropy of Energy & The entropy of sub-frames' normalized energies. It can be interpreted as a measure of abrupt changes. \\ \hline
Spectral Centroid & The center of gravity of the spectrum.\\ \hline
Spectral Spread & The second central moment of the spectrum.\\ \hline
Spectral Entropy & Entropy of the normalized spectral energies for a set of sub-frames.\\ \hline
Spectral Flux & The squared difference between the normalized magnitudes of the spectra of the two successive frames.\\ \hline
Spectral Rolloff & The frequency below which 90\% of the magnitude distribution of the spectrum is concentrated.\\ \hline
Mel-frequency coefficients (1-13) & Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients form a cepstral representation where the frequency bands are not linear but distributed according to the mel-scale.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `X` rather than `l` to specify at least one of the columns (probably the second).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one column must be of type `X` in a `tabularx` environment.

In addition:

- avoid `tabu` like the plague;
- avoid vertical rules if using `booktabs` and/or you want nice-looking tables;
- use `booktabs` rules consistently: don't mix `\hline` with `\toprule`, for example;
- never use `h` as the sole placement option for a float: it means 'here, if there is room', so what should LaTeX do if there isn't room?

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
% \usepackage{tabu}% avoid like the plague
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]% never use h as the sole specifier
  \small
  \captionsetup{font=small}
  \centering
  \caption{Description of the features employed in this project.}
  \label{table:1}
  \begin{tabularx}{1.0\textwidth}{lX}% avoid vertical rules with booktabs
    \toprule
    \textbf{Feature} & \textbf{Description}\\ \midrule
    Zero Crossing Rate & The rate of sign-changes of the signal during the duration of a particular frame. \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    Energy & The sum of squares of the signal values, normalized by the respective frame length. \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    Entropy of Energy & The entropy of sub-frames' normalized energies. It can be interpreted as a measure of abrupt changes. \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    Spectral Centroid & The center of gravity of the spectrum.\\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    Spectral Spread & The second central moment of the spectrum.\\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    Spectral Entropy & Entropy of the normalized spectral energies for a set of sub-frames.\\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    Spectral Flux & The squared difference between the normalized magnitudes of the spectra of the two successive frames.\\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    Spectral Rolloff & The frequency below which 90\% of the magnitude distribution of the spectrum is concentrated.\\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    Mel-frequency coefficients (1-13) & Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients form a cepstral representation where the frequency bands are not linear but distributed according to the mel-scale.\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: fitted table]

Comment: I would use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.25\hsize\raggedright}X >{\hsize=0.75\hsize}X}` and instead `\cmidrule` use `\addlinespace` :)

Comment: @cfr Thanks for a detailed breakdown. Appreciate it.